Multi-Factor Authentication supported for authenticating WiFi logons?

Is multi-factor authentication is supported for authenticating Wi-Fi sign-ons?  As I understand, it's not a concept that's supported by the IEEE standards for WPA2/WPA3. I know that EAP-TLS is the current standard for high-security Wi-Fi, and am surveying related options.

Do Wi-Fi clients (as a standard or on common operating systems) support prompting for 2FA?  I believe that MFA could work via 802.1x, assuming the RADIUS implementation supports it.  I did some testing and got our infra to trigger a push notification during Wi-Fi sign-on, but looks like that will require more work before sign-on succeeds.  I suspect that this would only work with push notifications unless Wi-Fi clients natively support prompting for one time codes, which I've never seen in action before.


Also, I know it's a bit off-topic for this site, but if anyone has examples of any vendors or technology stacks that support MFA with Wi-Fi, it would be helpful.

Maybe a security key as smart card with a pin and 802.1x EAP-TLS would work.
